# Sublime 3 HTML syntax highlighting in templates and template literals for Angular 2

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

In Sublime 3, how I can have HTML syntax highlighting in Angular 2 **template literals**?

[image]

... and also, how I can have syntax highlighting for **Angular 2 specific attributes in HTML templates** (like `*ngIf`)?

[image]

Comment: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Angular2%20HTML%20Syntax

Comment: @KeithHall thank you, that covers the case with external templates. Do you know any solution that work with template literals as well?